# Action cannot convert from A to B

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following method:

```
// Get Player Avatar
public void GetAvatar(Action<AvatarResponse> onComplete = null){
   if(!validate()){return;}
    Send(endpoint_getAvatar, onComplete);
}
```

Which calls this method:

```
protected void Send(string endpoint, Action<GameSmartResponse> onComplete = null){
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    StartCoroutine(Request(endpoint, form, onComplete));
}
```

And then runs this method:

```
IEnumerator Request(string endpoint, WWWForm form, Action<GameSmartResponse> onComplete = null){
    WWW www = new WWW(url + endpoint, form);
    yield return www;
    if(onComplete != null){
        onComplete(JsonUtility.FromJson<GameSmartResponse>(www.text));
    }
}
```

**AvatarResponse**

```
[System.SerializableAttribute]
public class AvatarResponse : GameSmartResponse {

    public string avatar;

    public static AvatarResponse CreateFromJSON(string jsonString){
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<AvatarResponse>(jsonString);
    }

}
```

I am then getting this error from the `GetAvatar` method

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from
'System.Action<GameSmartSdk.AvatarResponse>' to 
'System.Action<GameSmartSdk.GameSmartResponse>'
```

I thought that if I extended the object I could use it within `<>` so why is it giving me this error?

Comment: Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is the definition of `GameStartResponse`? How is it related to the other types?

Comment: @YacoubMassad sorry I copied the wrong error, but even in that method I get the same error.

Comment: @Servy your link doesn't help me at all...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn It explains to you exactly why you're getting the error that you're getting.  Other than having different types (which isn't really relevant to the question) there's no difference.

Comment: Why are they not the same type? AvatarResponse extends GameSmartResponse... Does that make AvatarResponse the same type as GameSmartResponse?